# Core Data: Can't find model for source store - only in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When my app starts up and my stack is initialized I'm getting the error:

> Can't find model for source store

However, it only happens when I run the app in the simulator. It works fine on my device. I've gotten this error before (again, only on the simulator) and I did a lightweight migration but now it's back. Can someone explain why it's crashing on the simulator yet working on my device?

Here is the extended crash log (I have one entity named `Date`):

```
Error adding persistent store: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x7f9ec3da42e0 {URL=file:///Users/AaronWilliamson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2783F030-EAF9-4E1F-AB85-615587FCD473/data/Containers/Data/Application/D07A03B9-5A94-4BCE-86D2-00063E57E678/Documents/DateAid, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Date = <9eee1fce 8d728bfd c3f90389 1b19cf43 9da883c4 212ed2b5 2a75b9ff 70dc4f98>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "77BBA37F-74CD-4C5D-ABCC-5A2AEB5CDD76";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store})
```

Comment: try this link it should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683366/magical-record-migration-failing-cant-find-model-for-source-store

Comment: Thanks @the_pantless_coder but my question is really why it's throwing an error on the simulator but working on my device.

Comment: Did you try reseting and clearing data from the simulator? Its kinda strange that one works and the other doesnt.

Comment: That fixed it. So does the simulator not have the capability to perform migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting and clearing the data for the simulator. I have had similar problems when performing migrations. That always fixes it for me.